# Possible to "downgrade" from Windows 10 Insider Preview (Fast Ring) to regular Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-insider

Initially upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 RTM, I'm using Windows 10 Insider Preview (aka "Fast Ring") for approx. half a year now.

Currently, it seems to be way too unstable to me.

Therefore I want to use the "regular" Windows 10 again.

Everything I found so far was [this Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/stop-receiving-builds) which basically boils down to using a recovery image.

My idea was something easier like e.g. just installing Windows 10 over my current Insider Preview to keep my settings and the like.

**My question is:**

What is the recommended way of downgrading from Insider Preview to RTM of Windows 10 while (preferably) keeping my settings?

**Update:**

I've ended setting up a new Windows 10.

Comment: You wait until the stable build of the branch you are on is released then you leave the insider preview.

Comment: Actually, the "leave" option, as described in [this Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/stop-receiving-builds) is _not_ available on my machine.

Comment: What build are you on?

Comment: @Ramhound In the lower right of my desktop it says "Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview, Evaluation copy **Build 14279.rs1_release.160229-1700**".

Comment: As I said in my first comment.  You have to wait until the stable branch release happens, then and only then, will you be able to leave the Insider Preview given your requirements of keeping your settings.

Comment: So is a fresh install of Windows 10 RTM _over my current installation_ an option to keep my settings?

Comment: No;  That isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot downgrade to a previous Windows version.

You can always leave the Insider Preview program or switch from Fast to Slow ring, but once you are on a newer Windows Build/Version there is no downgrade path. If you have the previous installation files (which can can delete with Disk Cleanup) you can downgrade to the previously installed version - but only to that version and if you didn't delete these previous installation files.

When you switch from Insider Fast to Insider Slow ring you will just stop receiving updates until a new Insider Slow version is released. Up until then you will stick with your newer Insider Fast build.
When you switch from Insider Slow to RTM version or choose to leave the Insider program you will also stay with your newer Insider version as long as the RTM version is older than your current Windows build.

The only way around this is by having the previous Windows installation files or by re-installing Windows from scratch.